# How to extract multiple nodes inside @shadow-root(open)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, shadow-dom, queryselector

I want to extract all banner images from this [url](https://shopee.co.th/%E0%B8%84%E0%B8%A7%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%A1%E0%B8%87%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%A1%E0%B9%81%E0%B8%A5%E0%B8%B0%E0%B8%82%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%87%E0%B9%83%E0%B8%8A%E0%B9%89%E0%B8%AA%E0%B9%88%E0%B8%A7%E0%B8%99%E0%B8%95%E0%B8%B1%E0%B8%A7-cat.11044959). I have tried

```
item = driver.execute_script(
            "return document.querySelector('shopee-carousel-stateful').shadowRoot.querySelector('shopee-banner-simple').shadowRoot.querySelector('img.banner-image')")
image = item.get_attribute('src')
```

But with this implementation I manage to get only one image. I could not find a way to get all images through `driver.execute_script`

Comment: Could there be a difference between ``querySelector`` and ``querySelectorAll``?

Comment: Yes it worked with a bit of more manipulation also. Thanks!